What's the most accurate translation for "Comic Convention"?
Comic Conventions, or Cosplay, Anime, Manga Conventions are popular all around the globe. How would native French people name them?
I found many possibilities:

convention d'anime
évènement manga
salon manga
festival manga


Festival MANGA de Deauville

Cela dépend vraiment du contexte, nous avons plusieurs termes. Si cela réfère vraiment à la culture japonaise on parlera de Convention Manga, mais si cela réfère plus largement à la bande dessinée, l'usage utiliserait plutôt « festival de bande dessinée. »

Each of those terms convey some specificities but not everyone is aware of them so you could see usages that go out of the norm.
This meaning of "Convention" is still not recognized by most dictionnaries. It is often used to refer to cultural items that wouldn't have been considered "respectable" a few decades ago (like roleplaying game or Japanese pop culture).
"Evènement" is extremely vague but it conveys no idea of a geographical limit so it makes sense to use it for something like "Pride month".
"Salon" suggests that there is going to be a general theme and a lot of stalls with people selling stuff or simply publicizing their activity. You don't go to a "salon" expecting to get drunk with fellow nerds. You go there to get informed about what happens in a specific domain (example: Salon de l'agriculture)
"Festival" suggests a relatively big scale (often a whole city) and displays of artistic items. People usually go there for an interest in the specific art form related to a specific festival (festival d'Angoulème: bande dessinée - festival de Cannes: cinema)

People do go to salon de l'agriculture to get drunk though.
